# Tips on performing a web penetration testing on a static website

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

No idea where to begin, I would like to ask for tips, direction and approaches when it comes to performing such a web testing.

Source code analysis is not within scope for this test. I intend to run scanning tools (nmap, nikto, etc) on the website's server.

Comment: How have you ascertained that it is in fact static? The `.html` extension is meaningless.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Why is it meaningless?

Comment: @HashimAziz [You can configure a web server to send any file extension to any script processor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389263/parsing-html-as-php-in-htaccess-for-apache-2-4) Hence you cannot blindly say that `.html` is static.

Comment: I wouldn't say the file extensions are meaningless, but they're definitely not reliable.

Comment: What's the reason for assuming the site is static? I've heard people describe Wordpress sites as being static content sites. It's not safe to assume the site is static just because someone else told you it is.

Comment: The site is deemed to be static as there are no forms of input, no search function, no login function, no administrative interface to manage the website. 

Source code is not available, but based on what I have seen so far, it is just a website with some pictures and a wall of text.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For a static web application there are things you should and shouldn't consider (this is non exhaustive):

For should:

- **Directory traversal:** Is there any directories you can access? Were these intended?
- **Inspect elements:** Did the developer or similar leave any comments in the client side returned HTML?
- **Server version:** Despite being static something still needs to host it! Is the nginx/apache out of date?
- **Host Setup:** Does the host go to a domain name (trust) and are ports restricted to what is absolutely necessary?
- **SSL Certificate:(Corrected)** Although there is minimal value in HTTPS on a static site, it is a baseline requirement for 2021. See [here](https://www.troyhunt.com/heres-why-your-static-website-needs-https/).

For shouldn't:

- **Injection:** If it is static, there should be nowhere to inject.
- **Access Management:** No handling of accounts.

If I was in readers position, I would confirm the application is static, write a minimal report, and deliver quick. I would encourage the reader to apply the [Web Security Testing Guide (WSTG)](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/) to what they are doing, only picking the applicable testing steps.

Comment: SSL/TLS is not just encryption nor a "quality thing". When used correctly, it guarantees that you are talking to the correct server, and nobody else can see what you are doing and they cannot inject malicious content. All websites should use it; there is no reason in 2021 to not deploy TLS.

Comment: Agree with some things @multithr3at3d. Will change SSL to a should look at, as even though there is minimal value it is a baseline, and a five minute job to do (no reason why you shouldn't). In terms of integrity and preventing injection I would argue SSL isn't the mitigator for those.

Comment: You could possibly do some reflected XSS if the static website uses some (eg. query string) URI input in (client-side) JavaScript.

Comment: I would add if you haven't XSS, SQLI, IDOR, file uploads.

Comment: @LUser "Injection: If it is static, there should be nowhere to inject."—XSS yes because that's client side, but it's static, there's no opportunities for SQLI or file uploads.

Comment: @multithr3at3d: *"...  it guarantees that you are talking to the correct server ..."* → no, it does not guarantee that. It may be an indication that you, maybe, talk to the right server but nothing more. A casual user may see all kinds of warnings and just skip over them. A less casual user may want to check the certificate but this won't help much because nothing in the certificate indicates that this is THE right server. It just states that the server SNI is aligned with the content of the cert.

Comment: @WoJ That is exactly what "correct" means in this context!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I do not agree. A correct login (for instance)  is one that HAS to go a certain way (your login and password must match, you can't do anything to bypass that". "Guarantee of the correct server" means that I am absolutely sure I go to the right one, and there is no way for me to bypass that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton People will not look at browser warnings and still access the server (so there is no guarantee that what you think is the server, actually is the server). There are hints and alerts, but no guarantee. If you find out that the server for BankWoj is https://wazaa.wazoo.com - how are you guaranteed that this is the right one? The cert will be LE so it is just hoping for the best.

Comment: @WoJ I don't understand the push to make the different classes of certificates less apparent on a website.  It seems to me that they should be made more apparent and educate users on them.  That could help in attacks like [this](https://www.wired.com/2017/04/hackers-hijacked-banks-entire-online-operation/)

Comment: You could also recommend that they recommend sub resource integrity measures (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).

Comment: @WoJ Technology cannot really solve social problems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is a solution to the problem mentioned, though.   EV and OV certificates show that the organization and it's right to use a domain are vetted by the CA.  But with the current state of things, that's invisible to users unless they actively check and almost no one even knows about the distinction between those and DV certificates like LetsEncrypt.  It seems to me we going in the wrong direction on that.

Comment: @JimmyJames Users not paying attention, or not caring, or not even knowing what to do, is still a social problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't completely disagree but it used to be that browsers would display different icons for different types of certificates.  It was poorly understood by users but instead of making the difference more clear, we now see no difference between them.  That's a technology issue.  I would go as far as to say that if you normally get a EV or OV certificate from a site, a browser should warn the user if it changes to DV or even block it.  That is a technical solution  that would have helped mitigate the attack I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 7):

You need to look for vulnerabilities in web servers, cache systems and also reverse proxies.

I suggest you to watch James Kettle talks to learn about HTTP attack surfaces:

- [Cracking the Lens: Targeting HTTP's Hidden Attack-Surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP4b3pw94s0)
- [HTTP Desync Attacks: Request Smuggling Reborn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A04msdplXs)
- [Web Cache Entanglement: Novel Pathways to Poisoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDxYWGxuVqE)

And also you can look for sensitive files/directories such as backup files, `.git`, `Dockerfile` or `.env` using tools like [dirsearch](https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch). You can also use [fuzz.txt](https://github.com/Bo0oM/fuzz.txt) as dictionary.

And also look for [client-side vulnerabilities](https://portswigger.net/web-security/dom-based) such as [DOM-based XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/DOM_Based_XSS) and [client-side template injection](https://portswigger.net/research/xss-without-html-client-side-template-injection-with-angularjs). BurpSuite has useful analysis to find DOM-based XSS, most of the time false positive but occasionally valid ;)

If your target is using WebAssembly, you can look for its vulnerabilities such as BOF that leads to XSS.

Watch this video on WebAssembly exploitation: [WebAssembly A New World of Native Exploits on the Browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81IQmmH0Bs8)